# Excel VBA: setting shortcut to Ctrl+Shift+5

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, vba, shortcuts

I've made a bunch of shortcuts to format numbers, as follows. All of them work, except the `Ctrl+Shift+5`, `Ctrl+Shift+6` and `Ctrl+Shift+7` shortcuts. The problem seems to be with the shortcut keys, because if I try to use another key (`Ctrl+Shift 1`, `2`, `3`), with the same function, then it works.

```
Application.OnKey "^+v", "pasteValues"
Application.OnKey "^+1", "'formatAs""" & "number" & """'"
Application.OnKey "^+2", "'formatAs""" & "number2" & """'"
Application.OnKey "^+3", "'formatAs""" & "date" & """'"
Application.OnKey "^+5", "'formatAs""" & "percentage" & """'"
Application.OnKey "^+6", "'formatAs""" & "percentage2" & """'"
Application.OnKey "^+7", "'formatAs""" & "general" & """'"
```

I've also re-ran the function that sets the keyboard shortcuts, in case any add-in or something was overriding my shortcuts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Those are already assigned, see [kb](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-Excel-6a4319ef-8ea9-45d1-bd98-f238bf953ba6)

> **Ctrl+Shift+%**  Applies the Percentage format with no decimal places.
>
> **Ctrl+Shift+^**  Applies the Scientific number format with two decimal places.
>
> **Ctrl+Shift+&**  Applies the outline border to the selected cells.

Comment: But can't I overwrite them? For example, `Ctrl+Shift+!` "Applies the Number format with two decimal places, thousands separator, and minus sign (-) for negative values.", but I could override it.

Comment: Are you sure your macro overrides it? What errors do you get for some that you don't get for others?

Comment: `Application.OnKey "^+1", "'formatAs""" & "number" & """'"` > works as intended when `Ctrl+Shift+!` is pressed.  
`Application.OnKey "^+5", "'formatAs""" & "percentage" & """'"` > doesn't do anything when `Ctrl+Shift+%` is pressed. I even added a breakpoint on the `formatAs` function, but it's not called on the 2nd case.